# How to continually monitor a bluetooth Characteristic?

Tags: bluetooth, react-native, react-native-ble-plx

I have a React Native application. Im trying to get Glucose measurements from a peripheral.

theres a `Data Transfer` option on the peripheral where it'll transfer data from the peripheral device via bluetooth.

I can retrieve and decode the data off the peripheral but i cant continually monitor Glucose characteristic. i.e if i add a new data to peripheral and select `Data Transfer` option the second time around i dont get latest data.

any ideas on what i should be doing to achieve this?

im using `react-native-ble-plx` library

```
this.manager.monitorCharacteristicForDevice(
   device.id,
   '00001808-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb',
   '00002a18-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'
)
```

Comment: There is an issue open which sounds very similar: https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/issues/446

Comment: thanks @ukBaz. the peripheral device iv got only supports `Glucose` but not `Continuous Glucose` characteristic. im assuming the answer to my original question is to monitor `Continuous Glucose` characteristic. unfortunately this peripheral doesnt have this characteristic. interestingly, with the manufacturers app i can transfer data multiple times from the peripheral and the app shows latest data. im wondering how their achieving this or is there something in Bluetooth api im missing.

Comment: You might be able to get more information about what is going on by looking at the BTSnoop logs https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/verifying_debugging#debugging-with-logs